# What's the difference between these approaches to reference bundled CSS in ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, css, bundle, webforms, .net-4.5

I used Visual Studio 2012 and the built-in template (under Add -> New Project) to create a brand new ASP.NET Web Forms web application project targeting .NET Framework 4.5. Inside the Site.Master page provided by default I see some markup that includes CSS on the page, which looks like this:

```
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
```

However, I noticed that I can potentially use this other code instead....

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/css") %>
```

When I look at the rendered page, the result appears to be the same thing.  What is the difference between using webopt:BundleReference and using Styles.Render?

Is one of these a better approach than the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<%: Styles.Render %>` syntax is for ASP.NET MVC (which can't use ASP.NET Controls as there is no real page context for them to use). The `BundleReference` Control is for WebForms.

ASP.NET MVC can use WebForms as a view engine as an alternative to Razor (where you see too many '@' symbols), that's why there's a bit of crossover.

I imagine they added the Control to keep things consistent, rather than requiring WebForms folks to use the page's render function (the `<%` tags).

Comment: What is funny is that by default the master page has a BundleReference for some CSS and uses a Scripts.Render for the Modernizr JavaScript.  It seems like they could have been consistent and used the same methodology for both.  Like use BundleReference for both....

Comment: Do you have any idea why both approaches would be used in the same master page by default?  Is there some implication css files should be rendered using webopt:BundleReference control and JS files should be rendered using Scripts.Render?

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because I believe it comes the closest to explaining why both of these options exist, even though they achieve the same end goal.  Although I still feel it is unclear why MS would use **both** approaches in the same master page.... but I don't see any answers to that question yet.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ClearCloud8 I think the different between `<%: Scripts.Render("") %>` and `<asp:ScriptManager>` is that `Scripts.Render` can be placed inside `<head>` where `ScriptManager` can only be placed inside `<form runat="server">`, if you use [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) then `Scripts.Render` is the only choice.

Answer (score 2):

> When I look at the rendered page, the result appears to be the same
>   thing. What is the difference between using webopt:BundleReference and
>   using Styles.Render?

As understand it, the BundleReference is used not only for including script and style references, but for bundling them together for efficiency of bandwidth. See the tutorial [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification). I think the latter is just a helper for including one or more scripts that fit URL pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, both of these approaches appear to be performing bundling and minification.  (I just tested this by turning off debug in web.config, running, and examining page source.)  So... unfortunately the difference between these approaches remains a mystery to me.... unless it is actually just an alternative for WebForms folks to use as Dai suggested.

Comment: On further testing, I think you're correct. I have found one significant difference between using `<webopt:BundleReference />` and `<%: Styles.Render() %>` however. You can specify an array of style references using the Styles helper class, e.g. `<%: Styles.Render("~/Content/base/themes/css", "~/Content/css") %>`